# 301 direct special characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Ok I know that

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

works for whole site to redirect for example.

I need to get `http://www.example.com]` to link to `http://www.example.com`
All my current combinations produce either a 404 or 
When i currently click on `http://www.example.com]` it goes to `http://www.example.com/%5d` which produces a 404 error.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to just strip `]` from end of URL or have other characters as well?

Comment: I just would like to strip it away, basically I have a link from a website that i would like to go to the correct website instead of an error. They are uncontactable so need to do it at my end.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)\]$ /$1 [L,B,R=301]` should work

Comment: Did that help??